# hello, the modal box appears in all posts ,I need it on the homepage

Tags: jquery

I have a modal box on the homepage but after I close the modal box it appears again when I see posts,I need it only on the homepage,its appears in all posts,can you help me?

I'm using

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $('.ik-hide').on('click', function () {
        $('.ik-modal').fadeOut(170);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the html for `.ik-modal`? that would be usefull to see, and where can that code be found, is a post a new page and exists the `.ik-modal` there too?

Comment: this is 

<div class='ik-modal'>
<span class='ik-hide'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></span>
<div class='ik-logo'><img border='0' data-original-height='100' data-original-width='100' src='https://myimg.png'/></div>
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>more</p>
<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-cloud-download'></i> Download </a>
</div>